# Can I change the output of jasmine-node to show the passing tests in the console as well as the failing?

Tags: node.js, testing, jasmine

I have the following file that runs when I run `node test.js`.

```
var Jasmine = require('jasmine');
var jasmine = new Jasmine();
var request = require('request');

describe("test", function(){
    it("works", function(){
        expect(5 + 2).toEqual(4);
    });

    it("should respond with hello world", function(done){
        request('http://localhost:3000/', function(err, res, body){
            expect(body).toEqual('hello world');
            done();
        })
    });
})

jasmine.execute();
```

And this gives me the following output:

```
Started
F.

Failures:
1) test works
  Message:
    Expected 7 to equal 4.
  Stack:
    Error: Expected 7 to equal 4.
        at Object.<anonymous> 

2 specs, 1 failure
Finished in 0.037 seconds
```

Obviously one fails, showing the F, and one passes, showing the dot. Can I change this configuration to have it show both the passing and the failing tests?

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to use a [custom reporter](https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/custom_reporter.html).  I recommend using [jasmine-console-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-console-reporter), which will give you nicely formatted output that will include all tests that ran (not just the failed ones).  Your original script would change to the following:

```
var Jasmine = require("jasmine");
var jasmine = new Jasmine();
var request = require('request');

// Register a Custom Reporter
const Reporter = require('jasmine-console-reporter');
jasmine.jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new Reporter());

describe("test", function(){
    it("works", function(){
        expect(5 + 2).toEqual(4);
    }); 

    it("should respond with hello world", function(done){
        request('http://localhost:3000/', function(err, res, body){
            expect(body).toEqual('hello world');
            done();
        })  
    }); 
})

jasmine.execute();
```

Note that if you are using the jasmine command line to run the tests (and so Jasmine has exported its helpers into your namespace), your code would be as follows:

```
const Reporter = require('jasmine-console-reporter');
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new Reporter());
```

I personally find it easiest to use that with **Gulp** and [gulp-jasmine](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jasmine) to make the definition clear and in one place, while also allowing me to run build steps prior to the tests:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const jasmine = require('gulp-jasmine');
const Reporter = require('jasmine-console-reporter');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.src('spec/**/*.js')
        .pipe(jasmine({
            reporter: new Reporter()
        }));
});
```

Comment: With jasmine-spec-reporter > 3.0.0, you need to retrive the reporter this way: 

    `const Reporter = require('jasmine-console-reporter').SpecReporter;`